# Checbox checked on telerik grid for mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, checkbox, telerik-grid

Telerik grid for mvc :
I have a checkbox which show status of item. everything is fine but either Status is true or false checkbox is checked.

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Status).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='Status' checked='<#= Status#>' value='<#= Status#>' onclick='checkboxClicked(\"<#= Id #>\")' />");
```

how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Status).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='Status' <#= Status? checked='checked' : '' #> value='<#= Status#>' onclick='checkboxClicked(\"<#= Id #>\")' />");
```